# Any long form literature websites in Russian?

Tags: resources, литература

I'm a big fan of websites like longform.org in English, which post longer-length articles (mostly non-fiction) from newspapers, magazines, etc. Can anyone recommend a similar resource in Russian? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have found some sites with articles for you:

http://elgreloo.net/

http://www.youknowthat.ru/temi/anomali

Comment: FYI: These are mostly "How-to" and "self-improvement" articles. They do not look anything like the types of articles available at longform.org.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then try livelib.ru , honestly this is the best site about books, mostly russian books, almost all of them provided with a quite long review and  a opinion. So good luck ))

Answer (score 0):

samlib.ru contains some amount of articles, but it is mostly a fiction site and is very poorly categorized.

Most long articles I read come from blogs in livejournal.

Many web-communities maintain specialized resourses, like habrahabr.ru for IT wannabes, rolemancer.ru  for tabletop rpg gamers, linux.org.ru for it-trolls and lurkmore.ru for bitards.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://primerussia.ru/ page. They publish interesting articles on literature, philosophy, art, society and the authors usually are experts in the fields they are writing about.

Answer (score -1):

Colta.ru is a site with mainly intelligent essays on contemporary Russian society. That should fit your bill.

Comment: "COLTA.RU (бывший OpenSpace.ru) — единственное в России большое общественное СМИ" - the definition of the site on its "About" page does not match OPs request. It's not from different sources and not about long texts (though you can find long articles there).

Comment: You are right. I may have mixed up with another great source of essays in Russian I cannot remember for the moment. [russ.ru](http://www.russ.ru) probably is a better option.

Answer (score -1):

http://lib.ru/ has a wide range of books by classic and modern authors. Mainly fiction and no periodicals though.

Comment: Author wants "articles (mostly non-fiction) from newspapers, magazines", not a classic/modern books.

Comment: Okay, but the title says: Any long form literature websites in Russian? Don't think that my comment would be too useless. Moreover, if I'm not mistaken lib.ru also has some periodicals.

Comment: Title is too short to express what you really want to get. That's why the post has body. Sometimes even post itself has incomplete information because original poster answers in comments. So in many cases you cannot give a good answer by looking at the post title only.

Comment: Has my comment offended you? Sorry if so ;)